# How can I create a HTML-table with these Json data?

Tags: html, json, html-table

I need I simple table with these data. I want one row with "country" ,one row with "number of trophies and one row with "games by Woman".

"England": {
      "Number of trophies": "3",
      "Games by Woman": {
        "2007": 14957,
        "2008": 14259,
        "2009": 16519,
        "2010": 17748,
        "2011": 18925,
        "2012": 19155,
        "2013": 15327,
        "2014": 11511,
        "2015": 11783,
        "2016": 11000,
        "2017": 16185,
        "2018": 16114
        }

```
  }

"France": {
  "Number of trophies": "5",
  "Games by Woman": {
    "2007": 15044,
    "2008": 15352,
    "2009": 15680,
    "2010": 15919,
    "2011": 126263,
    "2012": 16565,
    "2013": 16781,
    "2014": 16913,
    "2015": 17001,
    "2016": 17274,
    "2017": 17527,
    "2018": 17766
     }

   }
 "Germany": {
  "Number of trophies": "8",
  "Games by Woman": {
    "2007": 12044,
    "2008": 23520,
    "2009": 25680,
    "2010": 25919,
    "2011": 22623,
    "2012": 26565,
    "2013": 36781,
    "2014": 36913,
    "2015": 37001,
    "2016": 37274,
    "2017": 39527,
    "2018": 37766
     }
   }
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What language are using?

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: Provide more description of your problem.